# Add events for elements from a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, event-handling, handlebars.js

Using `Template.foo.events({ "click .bar": function () {...} })` we can add the click event to the `.bar` element which works fine.

How should I change `click .bar` to select `.bar` from a specific container (e.g. `#items`)?

I tried `click #items .bar` but that didn't work.

Currently I do that using jQuery inside of the `rendered` method:

```
$("#items").on("click", ".bar", function () {...});
```

What's the equivalent of this in Meteor templates (using `events(...)`)?